# SharePoint Online html pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, html, publishing-page

How can I run the html pages in the browser, because when I add a page with html extension, it downloads as if it were a document.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to Modern Pages or Classic Pages?

Comment: I mean html files

Comment: No, that i understand that you want to render an HTML file. But where you want to render it? On a SharePoint Classic Page or Modern Page or directly using file URL? In case its classic page, you can use `Content Editor Web Part` and paste the URL to file in document library. In case you want to render directly, change the extension to aspx. For modern page, I am searching right now what are the possible ways.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround try to rename **yourhtmlpage.htm** to **yourhtmlpage.aspx** then it will be displaying in the browser.